# ASP.NET virtual subdomain via Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm going to make pages accessible by subdomains like below:

http://product12.domain.com  instead of  http://domain.com/?productid=12

How can I do that? is it possible to create subdomains programatically via ReWrite or RouteMap?

Answer (score 0):

Subdomains, by definition, are part of the DNS. You'd have to create the appropriate subdomains within your domain management system. I may be wrong, but I don't think URL rewriting is supposed to be used for host redirection; you'd have to either set up routes to catch your query strings and redirect to another host, or potentially use IIS to do it.